# which UIButton event can act as a mouse over event like in flash

Tags: iphone

i would like to  create a UIButton it will zoom in when mouse over it,can anyone tell me which event can do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no mouse, only touches.  How can you hover over a button without tapping it on a touch based interface?  I dont think it works the way you think it does.

Answer (score 1):

Hop into interface builder. Drop in a button and look in the attribute window.

You'll see the section that has Title: Image: Background.  If you click on the drop down that says 'ALL', you can select several button states and set them accordingly.  Use the **highlighted** state for when the user presses down on the button.

This should get you to understand how it works. You can dig into the docs to find out how to do it programaticaly from there.

Hover on the iPhone is a touch. Unless you're tracking where the finger is and you want objects to react when you enter their bounds. But the highlighted state should get you there.